# Running on internet explorer 11 getting differ error

Tags: angular

when running my ng2 app on chrome all is well, but in IE11 I get an error of:

`EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'List []' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

any ideas?

regards

Sean

Comment: Same question here as well, have u tried with ie-shim

Answer (score 1):

the solution:

add:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.0/core.js"></script>
```

to index.html for support in IE